# how to call a function only once in a session in android

Tags: java, android

i just needed help with a function in android actually i am making a application where i will be needing a countdown timer and that countdown time is set dynamically from the database, and i am getting values for that timer from database through a function so when the activity first starts that function is called by default and timer works fine but when i go to other activities from this activity and come back to it again starts from the initial value, so how do i prevent that until the countdown timer ends(count downs to zero) ,
here is my code for timer:

```
public class fixtures extends Fragment {

    TextView txthour,txtminute,txtsecond;
    Handler handler;
    long seconds =40*60*60;
    Runnable updater;
    private ProgressDialog loading;
    int initStart;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup viewGroup, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fixtures, viewGroup, false);

        getTime(); //function that is calling time API

        View vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_fixture, null); 
        txthour =(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.Hours);
        txtminute =(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.Minutes);
        txtsecond =(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.Seconds);




        handler = new Handler();
        initStart = (int) SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();

        updater = new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                int sec,minute,hour;
                long  diff = seconds;
                System.out.println(diff);
                if (diff >= 1) {
                    sec =  (int) (diff%60);
                } else {
                    sec=00;
                }
                txtsecond.setText(String.valueOf(sec));
                diff = diff/60;
                System.out.println(diff);
                if (diff >= 1) {
                    minute =  (int) (diff%60);
                } else {
                    minute=00;
                }
                txtminute.setText(String.valueOf(minute));
                diff = diff/60;
                if (diff >= 1) {
                    hour =  (int) (diff%24);
                } else {
                    hour = 00; 
                }
                txthour.setText(String.valueOf(hour));
                seconds=seconds-1;

                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
        };
        handler.post(updater);

        private void getTime() {

        loading = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "", "", false, false);
        String url = Config.DATA_URL_Time.toString().trim();


        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String responseTime) {
                loading.dismiss();
                showJSONTime(responseTime);
            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                loading.dismiss();
            }
        });

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    private void showJSONTime(String responseTime){
        String textHrs="";
        String textMins="";
        String textSecs="";

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(responseTime);
            JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY_Time);
            JSONObject TimeData = result.getJSONObject(0);
            textHrs = TimeData.getString(Config.Hours);
            textMins = TimeData.getString(Config.Minutes);
            textSecs=TimeData.getString(Config.Seconds);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        txthour.setText(textHrs);
        txtminute.setText(textMins);
        txtsecond.setText(textSecs);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        handler.removeCallbacks(updater);
    }}
```

and my API file

```
public class Config {

    public static final String DATA_URL_Time = "http://xxxxxxx/time.php";
    public static final String Hours = "Hours";
    public static final String Minutes = "Minutes";
    public static final String Seconds = "Seconds";
    public static final String JSON_ARRAY_Time = "listing";

}
```

Comment: Are you sure showJSONTime is running on the UI thread when it's called from the onResponse?

Comment: yes quite , it is functioning perfectly and fetching values from the database

Comment: How is this fragment added to the activity? are you replacing/re-adding it at any point? That will cause your onCreateView to be called again, hence all your logic running when you return to this fragment

Comment: this is added with the help of a button and when that button is clicked this fragment is called so everytime button is clicked the fragment is called so this is the case

Comment: Are you sure your api gives an updated time?

Comment: the api gives the time i have fixed in the database , it depends how bigger i want timer to be , it always calls same value

Comment: is there any solution for this problem